# prove that when $R$ is a ring and $a,b$ in $R$ satisfy $a + b = 0$, then $b + a = 0$ is also true

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

> Prove that when $R$ is a ring and $a,b$ in $R$ satisfy $a + b = 0$, then $b + a = 0$ is also true.

It seems apparently true but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: See Mike's comment: What is your definition of a ring?

Answer (score 5):

This is true by the following ring axiom:

> If $R$ is a ring, and $a,b\in R$, then $a+b=b+a$.

Therefore, if $a+b=0$, then $b+a=a+b=0$.

Comment: Commutativity of addition actually follows from the rest of the ring axioms: $(1+1)(x+y)$ equals $x+y + x+y$ by one of the distributive laws, but also equals $x+x+y+y$ by the other. Cancelling, we get $x+y = y+x$. So it is conceivable that Alice is working with a weak axiomatization where commutativity of addition is a thing to be proved.